# Compiler doesn't recognize precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio

my precompiled header is called `pch.h`. When I specify `#include "../pch.h`, the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the precompiled header and gives compilation error C2857. It does however recognize just `#include "pch.h"`, but this doesn't work for my files within a folder.

Comment: Add the location of the precompiled header file to the include paths for your project.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled headers, "Precompiled header file" must also be `../pch.h`

Comment: Recommendation:  Don't use precompiled headers unless you have a huge project.  If one of the header files (in the pch) is changed, the whole project needs to be rebuild.  They are a pain to use unless your building enough files to see a significant decrease in the time to build your project.

Comment: May I know if your problem been solved. Could  you provide a a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: No it hasn't been solved. I just turned off precompiled headers for the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

What Hans said works for me. Please check if your path is correct.

If `../` is not used, you can also check the settings below:

1.Properties > C/C++>Add Additional Directories

2.Precomplied Header > /Yc

3.Precomplied Header File > pch.h